# Next JS - Middlewares - Error: URLs is malformed. Please use only absolute URLs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Good Morning! I've been trying for hours how to make redirect page in middleware. I read the documentation and I'm using NextResponse.redirect('/about') and i get a message that: "Error: URLs is malformed. Please use only absolute URLs -"

[image]

If I enter the Absolute URL as: http://localhost:3000/about the browser keeps executing the request several times as shown in the image below.

[image]

I try this solution in [Middleware Relative URLs](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/middleware-relative-urls), but the error persists.

Does anyone have any solution? Thanks.

Here is my code in _middleware.ts:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { NextFetchEvent, NextRequest } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(request: NextRequest, ev: NextFetchEvent) {
  return NextResponse.redirect('/about')
}
```

The folder and the files localization:

[image]

Comment: That's because when you use the absolute URL and you redirect to `http://localhost:3000/about` the middleware will also run, redirecting back to it again, and so on. Add a condition in your middleware to only redirect if the path is _not_ `/about`.

Comment: Hum, i didn't think about it, I'll try to run it with a condition and get back to let you know about it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 15):

The new version of next does not allow this anymore, indeed:

`next/dist/server/web/utils.js (136:0) @ Object.validateURL`

I have not consulted official docs, while my solution was to pass on the origin:

```js
export function middleware(req: NextRequest): NextResponse | null {
  const { pathname, origin } = req.nextUrl

  return NextResponse.rewrite(`${origin}/about`)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

While Decebals answer is also correct - [the official docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware#using-middleware) now mention you can use:

```
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/about-2', request.url))
}
```