# Next JS Middlewares - URLs is malformed. Please use only absolute URLs

Tags: javascript, next.js

This is the code in my `_middleware` file located in the `pages` folder it keeps giving me the URL malformed error anytime a request is sent:

```
const token = await getToken({req,secret:process.env.JWT_SECRET});

const {pathname, origin} = req.nextUrl;

if(pathname?.includes('/api/auth') || token){
    return NextResponse.next();
};

if (!token && pathname !== "/login") {
    return NextResponse.redirect("/login");
}
```

Comment: which line of that code "gives" you the error?

Comment: You can't use relative URLs inside the redirect, use ``NextResponse.redirect(`${origin}/login`)`` instead. See [Next JS - Middlewares - Error: URLs is malformed. Please use only absolute URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71307896/next-js-middlewares-error-urls-is-malformed-please-use-only-absolute-urls) and https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/middleware-relative-urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will deprecate soon if you want to use the redirect method you can create an absolute URL by

```
  const url = req.nextUrl.clone()
  url.pathname = '/login'
  return NextResponse.redirect(url)
```